# How to bypass password prompt when opening Money2000 files without password?

Tags: windows-8, passwords, microsoft-money

I have installed MS Money 2000 on Windows 8. Installation went without any problems. However, it asks for a password when I try to open the files? I never used passwords before?? The old computer is gone, so what I am going to do?

Answer (score 1):

You must use a version of Microsoft Money that is equal to or greater than the version of Money that created the file. See [KB318843](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318843) for more details. Money has been obsolete for five years and you really should stop using it.

Comment: I heard quicken imports money data files

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I have dug out a version of Money 2004 - and it works!